# Python- Kivy- Adding colour to buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I know this question has been asked before and I'm sorry but I promise I've read all of the responses and I don't believe that they work in my case.

I basically want specific buttons in Kivy coloured but for some reason it is causing extreme difficulty for me.

The rest of the program is just importing modules and run.

```
class buttonTest(App):
def build(self):
    b = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    btn1 = Button
    btn2 = Button
    btn3 = Button
    btn4 = Button
    btn5 = Button
    b.add_widget(btn1)
    b.add_widget(btn2)
    b.add_widget(btn3)
    b.add_widget(btn4)
    b.add_widget(btn5)
    f = FloatLayout()
    s = Scatter()
    f.add_widget(s)
    return b
```

As you can see above here is the class I want to use (I want five separate buttons), how exactly do I go back adding colour to these (text and background)? I will be extra grateful if this request is fulfilled by using a .kv file.

I have been trying to deal with this problem for about **24 hours** now.

Many many thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
btn1 = Button() #Blue Button
btn1.background_color = [0,0,1,0]
btn2 = Button() #Green Button
btn2.background_color = [0,1,0,0]
b.addWidget(btn1)
b.addWidget(btn2)
```

Take into account that colouring buttons only colours their texture. If you want a different colour+texture, you need to change the `background_disabled_down`, `background_disabled_normal`, `background_down` and `background_normal` images to a new texture and then setting `.background_color`

Answer (score 0):

This code won't even run - you need to instantiate the buttons with `Button()`, not `Button`.

You can also pass property values at this point, e.g. `Button(text='something')`. Of course, you can also modify them later, such as `btn1 = Button(); btn.text = 'something'`.

Look at the [button documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html) for information about the different properties and what they do. I'm not clear on what exactly you're stuck on.

For the kv language part, what is your problem with doing it that way?

Comment: For example, I want btn1 to be blue and btn2 to be red. Do you understand now?